# How unique is the id in ScriptDb (from getId())?

Tags: google-apps-script

Obviously, the id is unique within the instance of the script but is the id unique across all scripts for the user? for the domain (for Google Apps)? or is it unique across the universe (i.e. Google)?

If the data is shared across applications, can the id be a unique reference number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has confirmed it is only unique to that script:

[Apps Script Office Hours Questions](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/ahNzfmdvb2dsZS1kZXZlbG9wZXJzcg4LEgVFdmVudBjKhd8CDA/)

Comment: Megabyte's answer should be marked as correct, not your own, especially considering that he answered your question before you posted a self-addressing answer... I upvoted this because it is a useful resource, but Megabyte did answer your question in any case.

Answer (score 2):

The ScriptDB IDs are unique for stored data of a predefined script. The rest is an undefined behavior and it is not very reliable to rely on it. In not critical situation is possible, but **I do not suggest**, to generate unique IDs basing on

- Current Time. `var now = new Date();`
- Current Application ID. Mainly it exists but not in 100% cases. `var id = UiApp.getActiveApplication().getId();`
- Current User ID. `var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();`
- A few Random Numbers. `Math.random();`

To get an ID is necessary to join everything in a string, to compute the string digest and to encode the result using the Base64. But this solution is not truly random value and it is better to ask Google to create an function which generates truly unique UUIDs.

The code is

```
function getUniqueId() {
  var now = new Date();
  var id = UiApp.getActiveApplication().getId();
  var randStr = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    randStr += Math.random();
  }
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId();
  var str = '' + now + id + randStr + user;
  var digets = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, str);
  var res = Utilities.base64Encode(digets);
  res = res.substr(0, res.length - 2);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean undefined behavior?

Comment: In current context, the undefined behavior is any feature which is not included in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_scriptdb). For instance, the format of ids returned by the `getId()` function. Now it is the upper-cased letter S and an 11-digit, sequentially increasing, number. And this format can be changed in future. The same issue is the ids uniqueness scope.

Answer (score 2):

** edited as per OP's answer/megabyte's comments **

It would appear that you can only rely on the ID being unique within the current ScriptDb database. When a database object is stored, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb) says that it is assigned an "opaque, immutable string value", and that it is a ["unique identifier"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptdbmap#getId).

It's a good question as to whether that ID is unique across a domain, or across everything *(edit - seems we can not rely on either being the case)*.

Comment: Hm, IMHO the statement `the ID is, at the very least, unique across all scripts for the user` is not correct. Basing on it, it is possible to expect that two users which use the same script, under theirs identities, can get the same ID for two different objects. I think, the ScriptDB IDs minimum uniqueness scope, to which is necessary to rely, is the script to which belongs the DB.

Comment: Thanks for replying @megabyte1024 - I'm really having trouble grasping concepts here. Can I rephrase and say "the ID is, at the very least, unique across a user's database"? Would that be correct?

Comment: IMHO "the ID is, at the very least, unique across a database" gives less possibility to confuse someone who will read the post.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that the penny dropped - I understand now that a database is tied to a project. I had it in my head that each user had one ScriptDb database (one single pool of Javascript objects) that any projects that they write would be access with getMyDb(). This is clearly not the case. Sorry for my confusion and for confusing anyone else.